# How can I upload a static HTML site to a Windows Azure Website programmatically?

Tags: c#, azure, webdeploy, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I am currently building a local static site generator in C#. It compiles a bunch of templates together into a hierarchy of plain old HTML files. I want to upload the resulting files to my Windows Azure Website and have the changes reflected live, and I want to be able to do this programmatically via my script.

As it stands, I'm having to upload the generated files manually using WebMatrix, as I haven't been able to find an API or SDK that lets me directly upload HTML to a Windows Azure Website.

Surely there must be a way to do this from code, other than just using an sFTP library (which, because it doesn't use the WebMatrix/IIS protocol, which I think sends zipped diffs, would be slow and would mean out-of-sync data during the upload while some files have been updated and others haven't.) I'd also rather not have to commit my generated site to source control if I can avoid it. It seems conceptually wrong to me to be putting something into source control merely as an implementation detail of deployment.

Update: WebMatrix internally uses Web Deploy (MSDeploy). Theoretically you should be able to build the deployment package yourself using the API, but 99% of the examples I can find are using the command-line tool or the GUI tools in Visual Studio. I need to build the package and deploy it programmatically from within C#. Any ideas or guidance on how to go about this? The docs on MSDN don't really show any examples for this kind of scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so I worked out what to do with help from a couple of friendly folks at Microsoft. (See [David's Ebbo's response to my forum question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/367e51c3-3ffd-4484-8fb1-f2119b723f15/how-can-i-upload-and-deploy-a-static-html-site-to-a-windows-azure-website-programmatically?forum=azuregit), and this very helpful info from [Sayed Hashimi](https://github.com/sayedihashimi/publish-samples/blob/master/how-to-publish-a-folder.md) showing how to do exactly what I wanted to do from the msdeploy.exe console app).

Just grab your PublishSettings file from the Azure web portal. Open it in a text editor to get the values to paste into the below code.

```
var destinationOptions = new DeploymentBaseOptions()
{
    // userName from Azure Websites PublishSettings file
    UserName = "$msdeploytest",
    // pw from PublishSettings file
    Password = "ThisIsNotMyPassword",
    // publishUrl from PublishSettings file using https: protocol prefix rather than 443 port
    // and adding "/msdeploy.axd?site={msdeploySite-variable-from-PublishSettings}"
    ComputerName = "https://waws-prod-blu-003.publish.azurewebsites.windows.net/msdeploy.axd?site=msdeploytest",
    AuthenticationType = "Basic"
};
                                                             // This option says we're giving it a directory to deploy
using (var deploymentObject = DeploymentManager.CreateObject(DeploymentWellKnownProvider.ContentPath,
                                                             // path to root directory of source files 
                                                             @"C:\Users\ryan_000\Downloads\dummysite"))
{
    var syncOptions = new DeploymentSyncOptions();
    syncOptions.WhatIf = false;
                                                                                   // "msdeploySite" variable from PublishSettings file
    var changes = deploymentObject.SyncTo(DeploymentWellKnownProvider.ContentPath, "msdeploytest", destinationOptions, syncOptions);
    Console.WriteLine("BytesCopied:       " + changes.BytesCopied.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Added:             " + changes.ObjectsAdded.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Updated:           " + changes.ObjectsUpdated.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Deleted:           " + changes.ObjectsDeleted.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Errors:            " + changes.Errors.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Warnings:          " + changes.Warnings.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("ParametersChanged: " + changes.ParameterChanges.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("TotalChanges:      " + changes.TotalChanges.ToString());
}
```

You might also be able to stumble your way through the [obscure documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.deployment%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). There is a lot of passing around of oddly-named options classes, but with a bit of squinting of one's eyes and flailing about in the docs it's possible to see how the command-line options (of which it is much easier to find examples online) map to API calls.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is probably to set up [Git publishing](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/) for your website and programmatically do a git commit followed by a git push. You can think of it as a deployment mechanism instead of source control, given that Azure websites natively support a backing Git repository that doesn't have to have anything to do with your chosen SCM solution.

Comment: It's perhaps a bit of sophistry, but you make a fair point. Still, I'd like to avoid using SCM for deployment if I can: it would require my dropping to the command-line in my code and interacting with Mercurial in that manner, which can get messy. WebDeploy seems like a good way to go, if only I can make sense of the poorly documented API.

Answer (score 1):

WebMatrix uses [WebDeploy](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) to upload the files to Windows Azure Web Sites.

Comment: Cool. I'm looking into this right now, though documentation and examples on my scenario seem scarce.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use the VFS REST API (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#wiki-vfs). The [diagnostic console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) uses this to work with the file system today.

Comment: Cool. My idea however was that I'd like to take advantage of technology like that in MSDeploy, which allows one to send zipped diffs of the changes rather than iterating over all the files individually or blindly uploading them all again (as with a typical SFTP approach). It looks like using the REST API would require uploading files individually.